# How to Collect The Ip Address In Php

Tags: php, ip-address

I am writing a program to enable users to register domains. So when they make errors i receive an email notifying me about the errors a user has made. So i want the user's IP Address to be included also in the email. How can i collect it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`

Comment: Try to browse before you ask such questions. Happy coding.

Comment: @dbanda Please try searching before asking a question. The very first result on Google if you search for `php ip address` answers your question for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the user’s IP address by using the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] or $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']